# problems with stackdriver monioring postgresql on a GCE

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, postgresql-9.4, google-cloud-stackdriver

I installed Stackdriver on a Google Compute Engine (ubuntu) and tried to configure it to monitor the postgresql service installed in that instance.

The logs show that it is able to connect to the databse, but then it fails when trying to obtain statistical data.

This is the result of when I execute the command "service stackdriver-agent status"

Any thoughts as to what I missed?

```
service stackdriver-agent status
● stackdriver-agent.service - LSB: start and stop Stackdriver Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/stackdriver-agent)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-06-13 17:41:15 UTC; 14min ago
  Process: 5024 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/stackdriver-agent stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5045 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/stackdriver-agent start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/stackdriver-agent.service
           └─5067 /opt/stackdriver/collectd/sbin/stackdriver-collectd -C /opt/stackdriver/collectd/etc/collectd.conf -P /var/run/stackdriver-agent.pid

Jun 13 17:55:15 prod-postgres collectd[5067]: parse_value: Failed to parse string as derive: .
Jun 13 17:55:15 prod-postgres collectd[5067]: db query utils: udb_result_submit: Parsing `' as derive failed.
Jun 13 17:55:15 prod-postgres collectd[5067]: db query utils: udb_query_handle_result (postgres, queries): All results failed.
Jun 13 17:55:15 prod-postgres collectd[5067]: postgresql: udb_query_handle_result failed with status -1.
Jun 13 17:55:15 prod-postgres collectd[5067]: parse_value: Failed to parse string as gauge: .
Jun 13 17:55:15 prod-postgres collectd[5067]: db query utils: udb_result_submit: Parsing `' as gauge failed.
Jun 13 17:55:15 prod-postgres collectd[5067]: parse_value: Failed to parse string as gauge: .
Jun 13 17:55:15 prod-postgres collectd[5067]: db query utils: udb_result_submit: Parsing `' as gauge failed.
Jun 13 17:55:15 prod-postgres collectd[5067]: db query utils: udb_query_handle_result (postgres, table_states): All results failed.
Jun 13 17:55:15 prod-postgres collectd[5067]: postgresql: udb_query_handle_result failed with status -1.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the official place to post stackdriver issues is in the google group:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!forum/google-stackdriver-discussion

Second of all: DO NOT monitor the system database postgres.. DUH!

Comment: Why not monitor the postgres database? What makes you think that "postgres" is a specific database?